# WPF Calendar selecteddate not binding + single click to select date?

Tags: c#, wpf, date, calendar

Short info: I'm trying to develop a program for the administration of a daycare center, the most of the "visitors" come here every day, but sometimes they want to come 1 day extra or want to stay home. So i wanted to use a calendar where the user can select the date's that the visitor will come.

I'm using WPF and the MVVMC patern.

Problem 1, i have a date for visitor A in the database, but when i try to bind to the selecteddate it doesn't work. if i read the date in a textbox i see the date correctly.

problem 2, i can not use the selecteddates of the calendarcontrol is there a work around? the user needs the ability to select and view more then 1 date.

problem 3, is there any way that i can modify the calendar so that each date will function like a checkbox, if i want to select more dates i need to hold CTRL and i really want a single click to select to keep the program easy to work with.

Thanks a lot,
Btw i'm just a beginning programmer, i don't have a lot of experience, i only have a nice idea and i want to work this out very properly, so please go easy on me.

Answer (score 0):

You should set both `DisplayDate="{Binding RegisterDate}"` and `SelectedDate="{Binding RegisterDate}"`.

Try it :

Xaml code :

```
<Calendar x:Name="MyCalender" DisplayDate="{Binding RegisterDate}" SelectedDate="{Binding RegisterDate}" />
<TextBox x:Name="TxtVisitorId" />
<Button Name="BtnBindDate" Click="BtnBindDate_OnClick" Content="SetCurrentDate"/>
```

Cs Code :

```
private void BindData(int visitorId)
{
    using (var context = SampleContext.GetContext())
    {
        var visitor = context.Visitors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VisitorId == visitorId);
        MyCalender.DataContext = visitor;
    }
}

private void BtnBindDate_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var id = int.Parse(TxtVisitorId.Text);
    BindData(id);
}
```

Visitor Class :

```
public class Visitor
{
    [Key]
    public int VisitorId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it is working when i set the displaydate and the selecteddate.

but how can i use it now for selecteddates?

Comment: `context.Visitors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.VisitorId == visitorId);` is selected of database.
What is your method for select from your database?

Comment: for a single date i use the same way as you described, but for a range of date i have visitor.presences.addrange, so far so good, i get all the data in my presences but i get on error on xaml that says that presences doensn't has a accessible setter.

So for now, a single date works like a charm a range of dates is still a no-go.